# Large folder copy between two local drives stuck at 98%

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, file-transfer, copy-paste

I just got a new hard drive and I am moving some files over from one internal drive to another, both NTFS. The file copy was going fine until this point:

[image: Screenshot of file transfer]

Then the transfer rate dropped to 0 bytes/sec and has been like that for about an hour. I'm afraid to cancel the operation because I don't want to lose/corrupt any files. This is a copy operation, not cut, so worst case I can just cancel and redo it, but it's ~300GB so I don't want to do that.

I'm pretty sure the files it is copying are not in use (it would have told me if they were, right?). I'm running Windows 8.1 64bit. Is there anything I can do at this point to get the transfer going again?

Thanks!

Comment: Cancel will be ok on a file copy, then copy All the files again, windows file copy will find all the duplicates and allow you to opt out of copying those. I have done this many times without issue.

Comment: You could also use Robocopy instead after the cancel to only copy what's newer I suppose recursively. The comments aren't answering the specific question but there are some starting point ideas.

Comment: I would do it in small portions.